# Free Radius + Captive Portal + MySql No valid RADIUS responses received

Tags: php, mysql, freebsd, freeradius

My Captiveportal shows very strange behavior. **Occasionally (2-3 times in 5-6 days)** it returns standard php error about exhausted allowed memory size. Logs says that in this moment FreeRadius does not answer

```
Error sending request: No valid RADIUS responses received
```

*That is why captiveportal does not work. Why this happens?*

This error disappear if I restart FreeRadius and Captiveportal.

I know that MySql is up and available.

My installation is Pfsense 2.1-RELEASE (amd64), 
Memory 2 Gb
FreeRadius + Mysql +Captiveportal

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 1):

It would be due to high resource utilization, you could try to increase the **`memory_limit variable in your php.ini.`**

you should also see if there are any memory leaks in your application, like executing certain section hogs up most memory,and try to optimise that